# Can't get the value of a var in another class

Tags: ios, swift, string, var

I'm trying to get the value of a String var from an another class, but when i'm using it on the new class, the value is empty.
I've got the MainViewController.swift class with :

```
    var movieIDSelected = String()

@IBAction func tapPosterButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    switch sender.tag
    {
    case 101: movieIDSelected = theaterMovieID[0]
    print(movieIDSelected) //The value isn't empty
        break
    }
  }
```

And the second MovieViewController.swift class with :

```
var HomeView = ViewPop()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let movieID = HomeView.movieIDSelected
    print(movieID) //The value is empty
}
```

Comment: this is not the correct way , show how you present **MovieViewController** then the solution is simple , plus window hierarchy if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current code try this in MainVC

```
if let home = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? ViewPop {
   print("home exists ",home.movieIDSelected)
}
```

//

but you should have only 1 segue to the destinationVC and link it to the VC not a segue for every button , then implement `prepareForSegue` and fire `performSegue` inside the button action to make the segue

//

```
@IBAction func tapPosterButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    switch sender.tag
    {
       case 101: movieIDSelected = theaterMovieID[0]
        print(movieIDSelected) //The value isn't empty
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToNext", sender:1)

        break
    }
}
```

//

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

      let des = segue.destination as! MovieViewController

      des.sendedValue = self.movieIDSelected

      des.buttonNumber = sender as! Int

}
```

//

```
class MovieViewController : UIViewController {

     var sendedValue = ""

    var buttonNumber = 0 // default value won't affect 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but when i put this, i've got the error : "Value of type 'UIApplication' has no member 'keywindow'"

Comment: copy answer again and try

Comment: Thanks, but now.. i've got the error "Could not cast value of type 'CornTime.MovieViewController' (0x104334160) to 'CornTime.MainViewController' (0x104333cf0)."

Comment: I meant to add the above vars to **MovieViewController** , copy them only and paste to that class , copy answer again

Comment: Oh thanks !!! That now worked for me ! Ver very very bug thanks for your help and your time !